# Autocomplete label not displaying data on hidden Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Autocomplete label not displaying data on hidden input field with display:none Attribute after showing.

I am trying to autocomplete data from MySQL database with the below-given script. It is not displaying label while it is giving correct response in developer tool network console. When I show the div with the .show() method, the autocomplete not displaying label .

```
    function openSearchDiv(){
        $('.search').show();  
    }

$(document).on('focus','#search',function(){
$(this).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'products.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name_startsWith: request.term,
                        type: 'type'
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: item['id'],
                                    value: item['id'],
                                    data : item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
            },
            autoFocus: true,            
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
               // $('#player').val(ui.item.data.player);
               // $('#marks').val(ui.item.data.marks);
            }               
        });
     });
```

```css
.search {
      display:none;
      margin-top: 20px;
      } 

 <div class="search">
 <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type Id" />
 </div>
```

I have checked this code out of `display:none` attribute it's working perfectly

Comment: have you tried visibility:hidden; instead of display:none?

Comment: @VikasJadhav still not working with `visibility:hidden;` .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not displaying label"? Could it be because of the `label: item['id']` in your `success` callback? I mean, maybe the `label` should be something like `label: item['label']` or `label: item['title']`?

Comment: @SallyCJ i am not sure, But its not showing anything where label should be displayed, While its working outside of this `display:none;` element.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my previous comment. But check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k8zevfLq/) which shows you using the `display: none` isn't an issue - at least on that demo Fiddle. So if you could create a Fiddle which would reproduce the issue, we might be able to help.

Comment: @SallyCJ [This](https://jsfiddle.net/ykL8aqso/3/) is the actual code in which i am facing this problem. I hope you could find out the issue.

Comment: Well, jQuery is not loaded because the resource URL is `https://jsfiddle.net/ykL8aqso/3/code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js`. Nonetheless, check my answer - if might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you look at [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8zevfLq/), I used jQuery version 3.3.1 with jQuery UI version 1.12.1 — the stable version as of writing.

But on [your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykL8aqso/3/), you're using jQuery 3.3.1 with jQuery UI 1.11.4 (a legacy version). And that's an issue because with jQuery 3.3.1, you should use jQuery UI 1.12.1.

And if you want to use jQuery UI *legacy version*, you should use jQuery 2.2.4 or an earlier version. *In addition, in your case, you should set the [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) option to the proper element/selector.* Example:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
  appendTo: $('#search').parent()
  // other options
});
```

I've forked your Fiddle and you can check mine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pefc891m/) where I basically omitted the AJAX stuff, but I didn't change any CSS, and used *jQuery 2.2.4 with jQuery UI 1.11.4*.

I've also forked the forked Fiddle and changed it to using *jQuery 3.3.1 **with jQuery UI 1.12.1***. You can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dn3me5q0/).

Comment: Thanks a lot its working now, thanks for your time.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help. Cheers!